# Cutting video (not in the regular way)

Tags: video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes

How do you remove part of the background on a video and put it on another video. what I mean is something like this https://youtu.be/UcRtFYAz2Yo?t=14 .I believe it has to do with mask or green screen or a combination of both but i'm not quite sure can someone help me out

Comment: OK maybe it is just me but putting "I am too lazy to" in your question is a **huge** turn off. The thinking goes if this person can not even be bothered to put the effort into finding out what they want to do, why should I bother trying to help? You should be looking for masking and rotosoping tutorials.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the help ill try to learn rotoscoping and masking. Also right now I cant be searching a bunch of videos to show